# How can I show a button when another element has focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple rows, each row contains two text inputs and a button. When user focuses on one of the inputs, the button should be shown. When elements lose focus, the button should become invisible once again. My best attempt:

```
const Input = ({inputRef}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Input</h1>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default () => {
  const firstRef = useRef(null);
  const secondRef = useRef(null);
  const it = useRef(null);

  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);

  function handleClick(e) {
    firstRef.current.focus();
  }

  function handleSave() {
    console.log("saving!");
  }
  
  function checkFocus(e) {
    if (!it.current.contains(document.activeElement)) {
      setEditing(false);
    } else {
      setEditing(true);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("focus", checkFocus, true);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("focus", checkFocus, true);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={it}>
      <Input inputRef={firstRef}/>
      <Input inputRef={secondRef}/>

      <button type="button" onClick={handleSave} style={{visibility: editing ? "visible" : "hidden"}}>Save</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Edit</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there any better/more elegant and efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: I actually think this would be possible with only css. Let me try to make an example really quick

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onBlur` and `onFocus` events.

This should work as expected, just adapt the logic on your component

**EDIT**

Edited the onBlur method.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  input: ''
}

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setValue(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }))
  }

  const onBlur = () => {
    if (!value.input) {
      setShow(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Input name="input" onChange={handleChange} value={value.input} onFocus={() => setShow(true)} onBlur={onBlur} />
      {show && <button>TEST</button>}
    </>
  );
}

const Input = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Input</h1>
      <input {...props} type="text" />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried exactly this before making my post. The problem is that when user clicks the button either input loses focus and button goes invisible before the click actually happens, so button's click handler never runs.

Comment: Can you make some logic to handle the `onBlur` method better? Like, check if there's something inside the `Input` and then avoid to call the `setShow(false)` maybe?

Comment: I've made some changes to the code above. I've kept the `<Input>` component because you have made that way and I've spread all the props to it.
In the `onBlur` method I hide the `button` only if the input field is empty

Comment: This is not what I want. When input loses focus the button should disappear regardless of its value. User can see and click the button only when the input is focused (that is, user is working with it).

Comment: I don't know then, if you want that the button hides when the input lose focus. The only thing that I can think about is delaying the hide action with a setTimeout of a 100 ms maybe?

If this is not helpful then I'm sorry but I don't know how to help you :(

Comment: it's okay, somehow dealing with DOM events in reactive frameworks is so tiring.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to what you're attempting using only CSS, which in my opinion makes it more elegant (and ever so slightly more performant, but really this is negligible).

https://codepen.io/danny_does_stuff/pen/QWMprMJ

```
<div>
      <input id="input1" />
      <input id="input2" />

      <button id="save-button">Save</button>
      <button id="edit-button">Edit</button>
</div>

<style>
input#input2:focus + button#save-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

If you wanted to do it in a more React way, you could do what Marco B suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713806/4746648)